# Network MIDI Protocol using iOS

Tags: ios5, rtp, coremidi

Is it possible output both live audio and MIDI RTP data from Bluetooth device of iPhone? Looking to leverage the Core MIDI library. Crucial is the ability to fire off both sources simultaneously with no latency.

Many thanks........